# Store language (ISO 639) as Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a MongoDB database and so far have stored some information as Numbers instead of Strings because I assumed that would be more efficient. For example, I store countries following [ISO 3166-1 numeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric) and sex following [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218). But so far I have not found a similar standard for languages, [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) does not appear to have a matching list of numeric codes.

What would be the right way to do this? Should I just use the String codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after raw performance and/or want to achieve really small data sizes, I would suggest you use either the three-letter (higher granularity) or the two-letter (lower granularity) codes from [IOC ISO-639-1/2](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes-keyword.php?SearchTerm=&SearchType=ALL&Submit=Go).

To my knowledge, there's no helper or anything for this standard built into any programming language that I know, so you'd need to build your own translator (code<->full name) which, however, should be trivial.

And as others already mentioned, you have to assess the cost involved with this (e.g. not being able to simply look at the data and understand it right away anymore) for yourself. I personally do recommend keeping data sizes small since BSON parsing and string operations are horribly expensive compared to dealing with numbers (or shorter strings for that matter). When dealing with small data sets, this won't make a noticeable difference. If, however, you need to churn through millions of documents or more optimizations like this can become mission critical.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably take this route. I think something like this npm package would do the conversion, I might have to adapt it to my users' locale.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-639-1

Answer (score 1):

If you're a fan of the numbers, you can use [country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), although they "only" represent the ITU members (193 countries according to Wikipedia). But hey, they have Somalia and Palestine, so that's a good hint about how global this is.

However, storing everything in an encoded format (numbers here) implies a decoding step on the fly when any piece of data is requested (with translation tables stored in RAM instead of DB's ROM). Probably on the server whose CPU is precious, but you might have deported the issue on the client, overworking the precious, time-critical server-client link in the process.

So, back in the 90s, when a 40MB HDD was expensive, that might have been interesting. Today, the cost of storing data vs. the cost of processing data is not on the same side of 1... Not counting the time it takes you to think and implement the transformations. All being said "IMHO", I think this level of efficiency actually kills efficiency. ;)

**EDIT**: Oops, just realized I misthought (does that verb even exist?) the country/language issue. Countries you have sorted out already, my bad. I know no numbered list of languages. However, the second part of the post might still be relevant...

Comment: Upvoted for second part, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code lists some common schemes for language codes, non of which are purely numerical.  If OP really needs a  number , then perhaps treat ISO 639-1 characters as a two byte integer?

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Since I will already have a layer of translation to each user's locale, I might store the values following the 2 or 3 letter standards.